# R not starting up

Tags: r

I keep getting this error when starting R.

> This site can’t be reached
>   The webpage at http://127.0.0.1:8854/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>   ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT

I have never had this issue before and now that is has started it won't stop. I keep restarting my computer with no luck.

Comment: R is a programming language, not  an application, what exactly you try to open? How? Can you post some screenshots?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve? Have you installed R? While posting it is always a good idea to mention your operating system at least.

Comment: Here is the > sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134) and > RStudio.Version()[-1]
$mode
[1] "desktop"

$version
[1] ‘1.2.1335’

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to open Rstudio server, which is hosted on your local machine. It could be that you are accessing the incorrect port. However, if you are trying to just access R, a simpler version would be to just download and install it (maybe using R Studio):

https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/